# Unity3D Problems disabling Mouse Controls to Conf. Xbox1 controller w/ 5th,6th Axis

Tags: input, unity-game-engine, controller

I'm implementing a Xbox One controller with the Unity Survival Shooter Tutorial:https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter-project

I'm on a Mac using an Xbox One Controller with Unity. I have it all working except for the 5th & 6th axis working with right joystick used to point character.

Through Edit>ProjectSettings>Input, I've configured 5th/6th axis in the InputManager to joysticks & changed the input manager to give the mouse no controls but the mouse continues to work.

The following code is used to make character turn by using mouse. How can I edit this to make character turn by Joystick?

```
void Turning ()
{
//Create a ray from the mouse cursor on screen in the direction of the camera.
Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

//Create a Raycast Hit variable to store information about what wash it by the ray.
RaycastHit floorHit;

//Perform the raycast and if it hits something on the floor layer...
if(Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, camRayLength, floorMask))
{
   //Create a vector from the player to the point on the floor the recast from the mouse it.
   Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;

   //Ensure the vector is entirely along the floor plane.
   playerToMouse.y = 0f;

   //Create aquaternion(rotation)based on looking down the vector from the player to the mouse.
   Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (playerToMouse);

  //Set the player's rotation to this new rotation.
  playerRigidbody.MoveRotation (newRotation);
  }
}
```